# MASM 64 bit - Cannot Get CreateFileW to work. CreateFileA works fine

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, masm, createfile

CreateFileW returns -1 and GetLastError returns 2 (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Running the latest VS Community 2017
Using Windows 10 with the latest updates.

Tried these register settings as well:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Policies]
"LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001
```

Code:

```
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern ExitProcess:proc
extern CreateFileA:proc
extern CreateFileW:proc
extern ReadFile:proc
extern GetLastError:proc
extern CloseHandle:proc
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERIC_READ            equ 080000000h
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL   equ 080h
OPEN_EXISTING           equ 3
OPEN_ALWAYS             equ 4
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.data
align 1
    gFileName       db "D:\C# Projects\TestAsm\Simple.txt", 0       ;Simple.txt contains Hello
    ;gFileName      db "\\?\D:\C# Projects\TestAsm\Simple.txt", 0   ;Tried this too.
    gFileHeapPtr    db 10 Dup(0)
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
align 8
    gFileHandle dq 0
    gBytesRead  dq 0
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.code
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main proc
    mov rbp, rsp

    mov rcx, offset gFileName
    mov rdx, GENERIC_READ
    xor r8, r8
    xor r9, r9

    push 0
    push FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    push OPEN_EXISTING

    sub rsp, 32
    call CreateFileA    ; CreateFileA works fine.
    ;call CreateFileW   ; Returns -1
    ;call GetLastError  ; Returns 2 > The system cannot find the file specified.
    mov rsp, rbp

    mov gFileHandle, rax

    mov rcx, gFileHandle
    mov rdx, offset gFileHeapPtr
    mov r8, 5

    lea rax, gBytesRead
    mov r9, rax
    push 0

    sub rsp, 32
    call ReadFile
    mov rsp, rbp

    mov rcx, gFileHandle
    sub rsp, 32
    call CloseHandle
    mov rsp, rbp

    call ExitProcess
main endp
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You do realize the `W` means it wants wide unicode characters? You are passing ascii, of course it won't work.

Comment: Why is it returning "file not found"?  CreateFileW is not smart enough to know what is in the file.  And, it doesn't care.  The ReadFile would also work, but in this case, the "Hello" would be mangled because the file contents are ASCII.

Comment: The `W` refers to the file name, not the content. As you say, it doesn't care about that.